# php include or require file

Tags: php, file, include, require

I think this is a easy question:

I have a form that when it's submited goes to another php file(file-list-php).

The file-list.php has the follwing code

```
<?php 
    require('connection/conn.php');
    mysql_select_db($db_name, $connection);

    include('connection/uploadFodler.php');

?>
```

the first two lines is used in other files without any error. So my problem it's in the third line, because it is never accessed. I put a script to alert when it accessed. like this

```
    <script>alert("TAAADAAAA");</script>

    <?php

        mysql_select_db($db_name,$ligacao);

        echo"<h1>welcome</h1>";
....
```

and the alert is never displayed.

What I'm doing wrong

Thanks

Comment: are you sure it is called 'fodler'? Maybe just a simple typo?

Comment: btw, if you include a file, if it is not exist or found, you only get php warning. if you require (it means you really need it) a file, if it is not exist or found, you get fatal error and it will halt the script.

Comment: yes. the fodler name it was wrong. Dam'it. I really need to sleep more and study less. Thanks a lot

Comment: :) Nice. In that case, can you answer your question so that the question no longer remains as unanswered?

Answer (score -1):

The problem was in the name of the file that I was including. It's uploadFolder and not uploadFodler :( Thanks Guven